# What is the difference between two sentences?

Tags: grammar

What is the difference between

> "This bad drawing of a dog is not acceptable for your project"

and

> "This bad draw of a dog is not acceptable for your project"

?

Answer (score 2):

**"Draw"** as a noun [means](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/draw):

> 1. someone or something that a lot of people are interested in
> 2. a competition that is decided by choosing a particular ticket or number by chance
> 3. A person or thing that is very attractive or interesting.

and it doesn't have the meaning you are looking for. You should use **"drawing"** in your sentence.

> This bad drawing of a dog is not acceptable for your project.